# Can I use a C++ class in python class as superclass

Tags: c++, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use C++ class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602580/how-can-i-use-c-class-in-python)

I am designing a software in python but I am experiencing some memory problems while implementing it with python so I am planning to extend my software with C++. So I was thinking **can I use C++ defined class and use it in python as Superclass and override some of its methods?**

Comment: What are you looking at? Boost Python? Swig++?

Comment: The question is very interesting, but a bit vague. You can write a C Python extension that implements a Python class, and once it's accessible from Python you can override whatever pleases you. Perhaps you should go ahead do it and come back with any specific problems you encounter.

Comment: http://efesx.com/2012/09/30/python-directing-cpp/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes.

You can **inherit** and **extend** the class using [boost.python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python). Please take a look 
[how](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/Inheritance) to do that.

However, to **override** the methods of base C++ class the way is bit more complex, please take a look at [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/OverridableVirtualFunctions) article on the subject.

Also, I would have considered to think how to avoid using inheritance and use wrappers instead for your C++ class, if that is possible.